# Sitecore JSS for existing Sitecore site

Tags: jss

The question may be very basic, but for better understanding about JSS i am asking this. The question is, can we use JSS for existing site created with traditional Sitecore MVC?
Because I am not getting component's data source as JS object in Layout service API response.

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: Sitecore 9 update 2

Comment: Do you have a licence that includes JSS? Also have you installed the JSS Server Package? this is required for JSS to work. https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_JavaScript_Services/90_Tech_Preview/Sitecore_JavaScript_Services_90_Tech_Preview_4.aspx

Comment: Yes I have developer license and it has included JSS and I have installed JSS server package. When querying Layout service API **[http://mysite/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey={276C5C1B-1D2E-4C2C-BA1E-A5C992D5225D}]**, i am not getting MVC rendering in response.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out the reason for the issue. In the end, we should have to include the rendering's placeholders in to the Layout Service placeholder list to get that in Layout service API response.[image: Layout service plaholder]

Comment: Update your question with these information. This is not answer

Comment: I believe this is the answer, it's just not phrased / presented clearly.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please verify